# JPA Could not serialize

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, serialization

I have this class, but when I make a query it throws an exception:

org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not serialize

```
@Entity
public class Google implements Serializable{

@Id
String nombre;
String pass;

public Google() {
    nombre = "defecto";
    pass = "defecto";
}

public Google(String anom, String apass) {
    nombre = anom;
    pass = apass;
} 
//Getters, setters..

}
```

This is the query, I am using JPA, hibernate and a MySQL DB, and the class implements Serializable I don't know which is the problem.

```
public void findNombresGoogle(Map<String, Amigo> anombresAmigos){
    

        List<Google> resultados = new LinkedList<Google>();
        Map<String, Amigo> nombresAmigos = anombresAmigos;
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("FROM Google google WHERE "
                + "google.nombre IN (?1)", Google.class);
        query.setParameter(1, nombresAmigos);
        resultados = (List<Google>) query.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line :

```
query.setParameter(1, nombresAmigos);
```

nombresAmigos should be a `List<String>`, not a `Map<String, Amigo>`.

Comment: I change this but now it throws another error: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: Not sure for this one, but could you try to add "select google " at the beginning of your query string. I thing that only HQL can start with FROM, not native query (neither JPQL).

Comment: @AlexisHassler you're right, only HQL start with FROM. [See here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html). Native query must be start with select.

Comment: It throws the same exception. In the log I have this: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'      The last query I tried was this: Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Google g WHERE g.nombre IN (?1) ", Google.class);
query.setParameter(1, nombres); //nombres is List<String>

Comment: Not really the same error... And I see that you've switched from a nativeQuery to a regular Query. Are you sure that nombre is not an empty lsit ?

Comment: You were right, in some point I make the list empty, that was the problem. Thank you so much!